# How is Shop class supposed to be access in line 60 of shopify.Session in the shop method

Tags: python, shopify

I am trying to use python shopify api with OAuth2 and working through the api, and 
am trying to move the the django auth sample over to oauth rather than legacy (and not use django, I am just targetting webapp2 on appengine for a much simpler example. ;-)

I am running into a problem where after getting a session shopify_session.shop() is called in my handler and I am getting a NameError: "global name 'Shop' is not defined".

Looking at the current code the implementation for this method is  (at line 59)

```
def shop(self):
    Shop.current()
```

but I can't see how the class Shop could possibly accessible. the class Shop is defined in resources.py and isn't imported anywhere in session.py.  Is this a bug in the api code, or is some magic supposed to going on or some other sort of setup run to inject that class into the session module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, that method has improperly ported from the ruby [shopify_api](https://github.com/shopify/shopify_api) library.  I decided to just remove it entirely, since it was already broken, therefore no apps must depend on it working, and even in the ruby library it isn't really using the session instance.  The only way it would make sense would be if it temporarily activated the session then retrieved the current shop.

The [shopify_django_app](https://github.com/shopify/shopify_django_app) example app is now updated with Oauth2 support, although the instructions and zip file for django on App Engine still need to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug to me. Not only the missing import, but also the fact that this method doesn't return anything. FWIW if there's any "kind of magic" (which I failed to spot after a quick glance at the sourcecode), then it's **very** unpythonic.

Comment: and the code is actually used in the django example, but I think it is never excercised.  Trying to work through the shopify app registration process has been making my head hurt. All code examples I have found to date use legacy Auth.  I have not using that code any more, but it makes me wonder what else is lurking.

I am not at all familiar with pyactiveresource and activeresource seems to do magic in ruby land, so was wondering if it does weird magic here too.

Comment: I have also noted that line 88 in session.py in the request_token method is contructing the POST url with the client secret token as path of the URL and not as POST params so the client token is passed clear in the request.  Which would seem to be a problem ;-)

Comment: This code isn't looking good.  It seems that line 88 of session.py should not be encoding client_id, client_secret and code in the URL but should be passing it is data in line 90 in the call to response = connection.post(access_token_path, ShopifyResource.headers)

Comment: hmm is this the correct place to discuss the shopify-python-api internals? There seems to be problems with it in its current guise

Comment: The library is following step 2 of the [OAuth2 authentication](http://api.shopify.com/authentication.html) when sending the client_secret.  It isn't being sent in plain text, since https is used, and the request is being made to Shopify, which already knows the client_secret.  The shop_url is provided from the params of a redirect from Shopify, and the params are verified to have come from Shopify using the validate_params method,which is used in the constructor.

Comment: Umm actually the current code in session.py Session.request_token does the following.  access_token_path = "/admin/oauth/access_token?client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&code=%s" % params  which means the client_secret is encoded in the URL and therefore is visible in the URL. https only encrypts the body not the URL, so any intermediate proxy etc will have both the api_key and the client_secret